# Logging from an abstract class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, logging, python-3.6

I have three Python modules: one contains an (abstract) parent class, and two contain classes implementing this parent class. Parent class has some concrete and some abstract methods, it looks like this:

`moduleA`:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import logging
class Parent(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        logger.info("Hello world from base class!")

    def concreteMethod(self, something):
        return something

    @abstractmethod
    def additionalMethod(self, something):
        """it needs to be implemented"""
```

`moduleB`:

```
import logging
from moduleA import Parent
logger = logging.getLogger("b_logger")
fh = logging.FileHandler('b_logger.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(fh)

class ChildB(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def additionalMethod(self):
        logger.info("Hello world from B")
```

`moduleC`:

```
import logging
from moduleA import Parent
logger = logging.getLogger("c_logger")
fh = logging.FileHandler('c_logger.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(fh)

class ChildC(Parent):
    def __init__(self):     
        super().__init__()      

    def additionalMethod(self):
        logger.info("Hello world from C")
```

Now if I decide to run:

```
from moduleB import ChildB
from moduleC import ChildC

B = ChildB()
B.additionalMethod()
C = ChildC()
C.additionalMethod()
```

I want to have two log files, each with one line from the parent class, and one from the child class.

My problem is, **how do I configure the parent class logger to log into the child class' log file** (not to its own)?

Comment: This isn't really an ABC problem; it doesn't matter here that an abstract base class is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a subclass to determine the logger, then you'd have to make the logger an attribute of the subclasses. The ABC could document this requirement with an abstract property:

```
class Parent(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger.info("Hello world from base class!")

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def logger(self):
        """A logger object (can be a class attribute) to log messages to."""

    def concreteMethod(self, something):
        return something

    @abstractmethod
    def additionalMethod(self, something):
        """it needs to be implemented"""
```

then set the `logger` attribute on your child classes.

If you need the logger to be a module global, then the name `logger` can make it difficult to reuse the same object as a class attribute. You can work around this by using a different name for the class attribute (so not `Parent.logger` but something else), or by adding an alias for the logger in the module:

```
logger = b_logger = logging.getLogger("b_logger")

class ChildB(Parent):
    logger = b_logger

    def additionalMethod(self):
        self.logger.info("Hello world from B")
```

The `additionalMethod()` method above uses the class attribute, but you are of course free to use the global names `logger` or `b_logger` too. Using `self.logger` would allow for further subclasses to change the logger reference again.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me! I implemented it like this: 1. added `@property @abstractmethod` in Parent (exactly like you wrote it), 2. defined and initialized `logger` as a *class attribute* in Child, 3. in any method of both classes I can now call `self.logger.info(...)`.

Comment: @machaerus: yup, setting the `logger` class attribute directly from a `logging.getLogger()` call is fine too, it doesn't have to be a module-level global first. I just wanted to highlight that case because of the potential for a naming clash.